# Hide Win 8.1 "tip" about "Switch between apps"?

Tags: windows-8.1, modern-ui, ux

I've just installed Win8.1 and I'm trying to set up IIS. When I open `Add remove programs` from the start menu I get the pc-settings app.

In the pc-settings app I get a "tooltip" or whatever we should call it, that hints me to "Switch between apps" by swiping from the edge. Well fine, but I don't want to do that right now, and I can't get that tip to dissapear.

[image: A tip]

The tip lingers on even into Visual Studio, covering my code.
I can't swipe because I don't have a touch screen, and also I'm on a multimonitor system that shows this tip in the middle of the screen.

Here's a screenshot for you, where I put the web browser slightly over the left monitor.
[image: Top notch UX]

So, besides rebooting, how am I supposed to kill this very informative tip?

### EDIT

When I kill the app by alt-f4 it dissapears right until I open the settings app again, then it's back.

**What I'm asking about is how to dismiss items like this in general.**

Comment: You can "swipe" with your mouse.

Comment: @gronostaj I can't swipe from outside that screen because then I'll deselect the app, since I'm on another monitor then.

Comment: My problem with these 'tips' is that every single computer at work forces me through the extended delay of the intro screen that starts with 'Hi' then I am forced to go through these tips EVERY time I log in to a new computer, AND every time I do that with a different account. It drives me nuts. Particularly as it usually happens when guiding someone through using the PC in the meeting room just before a big meeting.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Some notifications can be removed by moving the mouse cursor to the top left corner of the screen.

If that doesn't work, try this::

1. Go to Search and enter `Local Group Policy Editor` or `gpedit.msc`
2. Expand `User Configuration`, `Administrative Templates`, `Windows Components`, and lastly `Edge UI`
3. Double click on `Disable Help Tips`
4. Set the configuration to `Enabled`
5. Select `Apply` and exit `Local Group Policy Editor`.

When I did my research, I found the steps over [here](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/31098-help-tips-enable-disable-windows-8-1-a.html). Since then, no more annoying notifications from Windows.

Comment: Mouse to the top left corner works great. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for this. I just built a Windows 8.1 development VM and couldn't get the tip to go away since outside the screen was also outside the VM host.

The fact that this is necessary speaks to the length of road MS have yet to walk in a "unified" environment.

Comment: I found that for a VM you can do the Win+Tab twice trick to get rid of it.

Comment: This answer is a "fight against it!" kind of answer. If you would prefer a "work with it :-)" kind of answer, see the one I just added.

Comment: Thanks. I am surprised how MS created such a complete piece of junk after Windows 7. I have been using Windows since Window 95 and in Windows 8.1 I am finding myself asking question like 'how do I get to the desktop from here', 'how do I get to the internet' and 'how do I remove all these boxes and suggestions that I didn't want in the first place'. My dear old mother usually asks this type of question and now it is me. It is horrific.

Comment: thank you. good grief. i spent an hour before finding this. no thanks to microsoft. no wonder their device market share is not growing

Comment: This did not work for me but answer from SW_User worked great, right click on the task bar, select Navigation and uncheck the Corner Navigation

Answer (score 4):

This works for me by following:

Download and install drivers: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-8/all-drivers

Perform the steps mentioned to turn off App Switching:
a: Press Windows key + I.
b: Then click Change PC Settings. 
c: Then click PC and Devices. 
d: Then click Corners and edges.
e: Move the Slider towards off for the option Allow switching between recent apps.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is this guy's illustrated method.

Basically, if you have a non-touchscreen PC, you disable the touch screen input device in Windows' device manager:

http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how-do-i-get-rid-of-win8-switch-between-apps-tip-windows/

Disclaimer: I am in no way related to this guy. (His page has an exit-able "sign up now!" popup but it's harmless)

I'm running a licensed copy of Win 8.1 under a licensed copy of VMware Fusion on a Mac.

Comment: I somehow got `HID-compliant touch screen` under "Human Interface Devices" (maybe related to arduino driver installation), which needed to be disabled for the arrow box to disappear.

Answer (score 4):

1. Right-click the task bar 
   a. click `Properties`
2. Click `Navigation` tab
3. Uncheck all the boxes in `Corner Navigation` section
4. Click apply (Any corner "tips" that are currently displaying will disappear)

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: is this one time or does it have to be redone after each restart/

Answer (score 2):

Clicking on the arrow with my mouse didn't work but it did help when I pressed the Windows key and TAB (which is the keyboard parallel to switch between apps).

This does not prevent it from happening again somewhere else, but do the combo again and it's gone.

Answer (score 0):

To disable "Switch between application" screen on either of the laptop / computer; whether touch screen or not. Simple procedures is as follows:

1. Go to "PC settings" through "Search" option or as per your shortcut
2. Click on "PC and devices"
3. Go and click on "Corners & Edges"
4. "Off" all the "On" buttons under "App switching"

It worked perfectly on my system.

Comment: Why are you repeating one year old answers?